High memory usage in .NET 6 application with large strings retained in memory
I am experiencing unusually high memory usage (2 GIB for a 4 instances of System.String) in my .NET 6 application running in production. I've analyzed the memory dumps using dotnet-dump with dotnet-dump analyze and gcroot, and here’s what I’ve found:
dumpheap -stat shows the following:
7f6f4964f8f0 18,152 1,466,966,959 System.Byte[]
7f6f48fad2e0 51,915 1,981,308,612 System.String

gcroot with the address of one of the strings I have found the following:

86 unique roots
They are similar but not exactly these are some samples

    7f65298bf530 7f6f4facc029 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
        r15:
          -> 7f6547f46900     System.Threading.Thread+StartHelper
          -> 7f66486d8ab8     System.Threading.ExecutionContext
          -> 7f664863e128     System.Threading.AsyncLocalValueMap+MultiElementAsyncLocalValueMap
          -> 7f664863e140     System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.Threading.IAsyncLocal, System.Object>[]
          -> 7f66484d1b68     System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<Sentry.Scope, Sentry.ISentryClient>[]
          -> 7f66484cfe18     Sentry.Scope
          -> 7f6647cdb6c0     Sentry.AspNetCore.SentryAspNetCoreOptions
          -> 7f6647f9ae08     Sentry.Internal.Http.HttpTransport
          -> 7f6647f92a50     System.Net.Http.HttpClient
          -> 7f6647f92a20     Sentry.Internal.Http.RetryAfterHandler
          -> 7f6647f929d0     Sentry.Internal.Http.GzipBufferedRequestBodyHandler
          -> 7f6647f91da8     System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
          -> 7f6647f92188     System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler
          -> 7f66483de670     System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler
          -> 7f66483de648     System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler
          -> 7f66483de5b8     System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler
          -> 7f66483de4c0     System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionHandler
          -> 7f66483ddeb0     System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPoolManager
          -> 7f66483de1d8     System.Threading.Timer
          -> 7f66483de250     System.Threading.TimerHolder
          -> 7f66483de1f0     System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
          -> 7f6647c8d908     System.Threading.TimerQueue
          -> 7f65480e5990     System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
          -> 7f654811fb40     System.Threading.ExecutionContext
          -> 7f654811fac0     System.Threading.AsyncLocalValueMap+MultiElementAsyncLocalValueMap
          -> 7f654811fad8     System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.Threading.IAsyncLocal, System.Object>[]
          -> 7f654811f9c8     System.Diagnostics.Activity
          -> 7f654811de30     System.Diagnostics.Activity
          -> 7f66487bb6d0     System.Diagnostics.Activity
          -> 7f66487bb870     System.Diagnostics.Activity+TagsLinkedList
          -> 7f66487bb898     System.Diagnostics.DiagNode<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String, System.Object>>
          -> 7f66487bb920     System.Diagnostics.DiagNode<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String, System.Object>>
          -> 7f65480e3ad0     System.Diagnostics.DiagNode<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String, System.Object>>
          -> 7f695b756528     System.String

        rbp-20: 00007f65298bf550
          -> 7f6547f468b8     System.Threading.Thread
          -> 7f66486d8ab8     System.Threading.ExecutionContext
          -> 7f664863e128     System.Threading.AsyncLocalValueMap+MultiElementAsyncLocalValueMap
          -> 7f664863e140     System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.Threading.IAsyncLocal, System.Object>[]
          -> 7f66484d1b68     System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<Sentry.Scope, Sentry.ISentryClient>[]
          -> 7f66484cfe18     Sentry.Scope
          -> 7f6647cdb6c0     Sentry.AspNetCore.SentryAspNetCoreOptions
          -> 7f6647f9ae08     Sentry.Internal.Http.HttpTransport
          -> 7f6647f92a50     System.Net.Http.HttpClient
          -> 7f6647f92a20     Sentry.Internal.Http.RetryAfterHandler
          -> 7f6647f929d0     Sentry.Internal.Http.GzipBufferedRequestBodyHandler
          -> 7f6647f91da8     System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
          -> 7f6647f92188     System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler
          -> 7f66483de670     System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler
          -> 7f66483de648     System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler
          -> 7f66483de5b8     System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler
          -> 7f66483de4c0     System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionHandler
          -> 7f66483ddeb0     System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPoolManager
          -> 7f66483de1d8     System.Threading.Timer
          -> 7f66483de250     System.Threading.TimerHolder
          -> 7f66483de1f0     System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
          -> 7f6647c8d908     System.Threading.TimerQueue
          -> 7f65480e5990     System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
          -> 7f654811fb40     System.Threading.ExecutionContext
          -> 7f654811fac0     System.Threading.AsyncLocalValueMap+MultiElementAsyncLocalValueMap
          -> 7f654811fad8     System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.Threading.IAsyncLocal, System.Object>[]
          -> 7f654811f9c8     System.Diagnostics.Activity
          -> 7f654811de30     System.Diagnostics.Activity
          -> 7f66487bb6d0     System.Diagnostics.Activity
          -> 7f66487bb870     System.Diagnostics.Activity+TagsLinkedList
          -> 7f66487bb898     System.Diagnostics.DiagNode<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String, System.Object>>
          -> 7f66487bb920     System.Diagnostics.DiagNode<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String, System.Object>>
          -> 7f65480e3ad0     System.Diagnostics.DiagNode<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String, System.Object>>
          -> 7f695b756528     System.String

Using dc inside dotnet-dump analyze has allowed to to read the huge string instance which came as a surprise the content was filled with meta data about the class the methods invocation and every little detail about processes here are some of the examples:
{"Target":{"handler":{"Target":{"<>4__this":{},"act":{"Transfer":null,"TraceId":">>>>>aaa-432-
","TransferId":"15","SeqNum":"08","TriggeredBy":2,"TriggeredAt":"2024-12-․19T12:30:08.9597687Z"},"transfer":null,"blacklisted":[56]},"Method":{"Name":"<Initiate>g__Handler|0","DeclaringType":"ServiceName.Infrastructure.modules.ServiceOutgoing.Actions.ServiceActionAction+
<>c__DisplayClass10_0, ServiceName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","ReflectedType":"ServiceName.Infrastructure.modul
es.ServiceOutgoing.Actions.ServiceActionAction+<>c__DisplayClass10_0, ServiceName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","ServiceName.Infrastructure.Services.ServiceName+
<>c__DisplayClass102_0, ServiceName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","ServiceName.Infrastructure.Services.ServiceName+<>c__DisplayClass74_0, ServiceName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","ServiceName.Infrastructure.Services.ServiceName+<>c__DisplayClass78_0, ServiceName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","ServiceName.Infrastructure.Services.ServiceName+
<>c__DisplayClass81_0, ServiceName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","ServiceName.Infrastructure.Services.ServiceName+<>c__DisplayClass87_0, ServiceName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","ServiceName.Infrastructure.Services.ServiceName+<>c__DisplayClass93_0, ServiceName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","ServiceName.Infrastructure.Services.ServiceName+<>o__107, ServiceName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","ServiceName.Infrastructure.Services.ServiceName+<>o__72, ServiceName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","ServiceName.Infrastructure.Services.ServiceName+<>o__74, ServiceName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","ServiceName.Infrastructure.Services.ServiceName+<>o__78, ServiceName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null","ServiceName.Infrastructure.Services.ServiceName+<>o__81, ServiceName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","ServiceName.Infrastructure.Services.ServiceName+
<>o__94, ServiceName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

The string is filled with garbage like this.
I previously used Sentry for error monitoring, but after removing it, the problem persists.
Then I removed any and every kind of logging from the service yet the issue persists.
The configuration are mostly are the same for all the microservices
I have double checked all the registration of the services yet to no avail.
What could be causing such a large strings to be retained in memory?

I suspect this is related to Sentry logging, but it does seem excessive.

thank you for answer i did suspect that too so i removed all the logs and it didn't help at all

What does the memory dump look like with the Sentry logging removed? Anything look suspicious?

It seems like you are tracing the HTTP activity using diagnostic tools from dotNet, this activity is in early stages and not ready for production as they say: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/distributed-tracing-builtin-activities so the issue maybe in this tool not Sentry since you removed it and still got the same issue, hope this can help
More info:
If you are trying to trace the HTTP request it’s better to use openTelemetry and adapt your tool to use it instead of dotNet diagnostic tools
